# check which data-image on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ive the following buttons

```
<button class="image1-button" data-image="bg_images/1.jpg">button 1</button>
<button class="image1-button" data-image="bg_images/2.jpg">button 2</button>
<button class="image1-button" data-image="bg_images/3.jpg">button 3</button>
<button class="image1-button" data-image="bg_images/4.jpg">button 4</button>
```

with the following code

```
$(".image1-button").click(function() { 
var url = 'url(' + $(this).data('image') + ')';

$('#div1').css('background-image', url).fadeIn(500);

 // what to write in this if that it works...
 if('data-image="bg_images/2.jpg"') {
     here should something happen if button 2 is pressed
 }
```

how do i have to write the if condition that it goes in and fires my event?
thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($(this).data("image") === "bg_images/2.jpg") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: is it possible to say something like `if($(this).data('image') == 'bg_images/2.jpg', 'bg_images/3.jpg', ... )` means more than one comparison?

Comment: @TedMosby No, but you may do `if ( $.inArray($(this).data("image"), ["bg_images/2.jpg", "bg_images/3.jpg"]) > -1) { ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if($(this).data('image') == 'g_images/2.jpg' ) { 
    //do your stuff.
}
```

Comment: exactly! thanks very much! ps. you forgot the b at bg_images!

Comment: is it possible to say something like
`if($(this).data('image') == 'bg_images/2.jpg', 'bg_images/3.jpg', ... )`
means more than one comparison?

Comment: use `switch` :) Also what do you want to do exactly... If you clarify the output you wanna get, it will be easier for me to propel you in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( $(this).data('image') == 'bg_images/2.jpg' ) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
if ( $(this).attr('data-image') == 'bg_images/2.jpg' ) {
    // ...
}
```